# save multiple graphics in svg

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2

Assuming this script that generates two generic graphics "a" and "b"

```
library(ggplot2)

# dataset:
data=data.frame(value=rnorm(100))

# basic histogram
a <- ggplot(data, aes(x=value)) + 
  geom_histogram()

a

# dataset:
datab=data.frame(value=rnorm(70))

# basic histogram
b <- ggplot(datab, aes(x=value)) + 
  geom_histogram()

b
```

How to save the "a" chart and the "b" chart in two different files in .svg format with the size I determine. here I simulated two graphs, but I have 12 and I would like to optimize the process in a script, instead of using the export button on each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `for` loop to incorporate `svg` function to save graph in a svg format.

With your data, it could look like something like that. Of course, you have to associate each iteration of the loop to the correct dataset.

```r
library(ggplot2)

for(i in 1:12)
{
  p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=value)) + 
    geom_histogram()

  svg(filename = "graph%03d.svg", width = 7, height = 7)
  p
  graphics.off()
}
```

Does it answer your question ?